# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build when ValueListenableNotifier detects value change

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm using an `AppValueNotifier` to create a value called `showStreamDialogNotifier` that will change depending on some stream. When this value becomes true, I want to show a dialog box on my `Login` form.

```
class AppValueNotifier{
  ValueNotifier showStreamDialogNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  void updateShowStreamDialogNotifier({required bool? newShowStreamDialog, required String? newStreamDialogTitle, required String? newStreamDialogMsg}) {
    if (newShowStreamDialog != null) {
      showStreamDialogNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(newShowStreamDialog);
    }

  }

}
```

The problem is that when I try to call my function that runs `showDialog`, it gives the error in the title. Why is this error appearing and how do I modify my code so that it properly shows a dialog over the `Login` form when `showStreamDialogNotifier = true`?

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {

    Future<void> showStreamDialog({required BuildContext context, required String title, required String msg}) {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(title),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListBody(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(msg),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text('OK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      final globalsOneTimeRead = context.read<GlobalsProvider>();
                      globalsOneTimeRead.updateStreamDialogVariables(newShowStreamDialog: false, newStreamDialogTitle: '', newStreamDialogMsg: '');
                      context.pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
        );
      }

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        AppValueNotifier appValueNotifier = AppValueNotifier();
        
        return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
            builder: (context, globals, child) => Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                    child: Column(
                        children: [
                            Expanded( 
                                child: ValueListenableBuilder( //THE ERROR POINTS TO THIS LINE
                                    valueListenable: appValueNotifier.showStreamDialogNotifier,
                                    builder: (context, value, child) {

                                      if (value == true) {
                                        showStreamDialog(context: context, title: globals.streamDialogTitle, msg: globals.streamDialogMsg);
                                      }
                                      
                                      return Text('');
                                    },
                                ),
                            ),
                        ]
                    )
                )
            )

        

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you would like to show dialog, I will prefer adding listener instead.

```dart
AppValueNotifier appValueNotifier = AppValueNotifier();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    appValueNotifier.showStreamDialogNotifier.addListener(() {
      if (appValueNotifier.showStreamDialogNotifier.value == true) {
         showStreamDialog(... );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    appValueNotifier.showStreamDialogNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Also, you can try with postFrameCallback.

Comment: The `addListener` method isn't working. I am switching `appValueNotifier.showStreamDialogNotifier` from false to true, but the dialog never appears. I printed out the values to make sure it is indeed changing from false to true and also tested to make sure that the dialog box can open with a simple button press. So it seems the problem is with the `addListener` section

Comment: did you try putting outside the build method as I have included . Also you need to set value like `appValueNotifier.showStreamDialogNotifier.value = true;` if it still fails can you share a dartpad link

Comment: Ah yup - the problem was because I wasn't using `.value` when setting the variable to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){

  // Add Your If Condition Code here

});
```